# Changing UI element input value doesn't display changes in input

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm having a problem with changing an input's value. The code below works but **it's only setting the html value="geolocationvaluehere"**, the problem is that it doesn't display the text in the input (geolocationvaluehere), it's empty.

I've tried using `self.ui.location.val(loc.city)` too but with no success.

```
View.Form = MyProject.CustomItemView.extend({
  template: formTpl,

  ui: {
    location: 'input[name=location]'
  },

  onRender: function () {
    var self = this;

    this.saveLocationToStorage(function(err) {
      if( ! err && localStorage.getItem('geoLocation')) {
        var loc = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('geoLocation'));

        if(self.ui.location[0]) self.ui.location.attr('value', loc.city);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: What is `self.ui` ..? a `<form>`..? not sue how you expect `self.ui.location` to point to an `input`

Comment: What type of input is `self.ui.location`?

Comment: @KristjanKirpu in that case `self.ui.location.val` should work fine - see the JSBin in my answer. Does that JSBin work in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the value with the [jQuery `val` function](http://api.jquery.com/val/) rather than `attr`:

```
self.ui.location.val(loc.city);
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xoduwuhime/edit?html,js,console,output)